# WPF MVVM loading DataGrid Column Display Index when view gets activated

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Well, I've tried so many different things so hopefully I wont mess up to explain what I've tried so far.

As sidenote I'm working with Caliburn Micro and trying to follow the MVVM Pattern.

I'm trying to reorder the columns of a datagrid programmatically when the ViewModel is loaded (so the user can save their settings for the grid).

The Binding of the column properties is working and reflect their current values.

To test the behavior I've set up a Dictionary<int,string> with the DisplayIndexes and the ColumnNames in a special order.

```
public class OrderSumUpViewModel : Screen, IHandle<DialogEvent>, IHandle<LogOutEvent>
{
    public BindableCollection<UIProcessStepModel> ProcessSteps { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<UIOrderModel> OrdersBc { get; set; }

    private List<Predicate<UIOrderModel>> criteria = new List<Predicate<UIOrderModel>>();

    private ISaveAndLoadSettings settings;
    private IEventAggregator events;
    private IWindowManager manager;
    private ModifyStatus modifyStatus;
    private bool IsCancelationPlausibleThroughDialog;
    private string cancelMessage;
    public Dictionary<int,string> ColPositions;

    public OrderSumUpViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IWindowManager manager, ISaveAndLoadSettings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.events = events;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.events.Subscribe(this);

        this.OrdersBc = new BindableCollection<UIOrderModel>(new UIAllOrdersModel().GetAll());
        this.Orders = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(OrdersBc);

        this.ProcessSteps = new BindableCollection<UIProcessStepModel>(UIAllProcessStepsModel.GetAll());

        this.modifyStatus = new ModifyStatus();

        SetInitialValues();
    }

    private void SetInitialValues() {
        this.ColPositions = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            [0] = "ColPosDue",
            [1] = "ColPosCode",
            [2] = "ColPosStatus",
            [3] = "ColPosMat",
            [4] = "ColPosProgress",
            [5] = "ColPosQuantity",
            [6] = "ColPosUnit",
            [7] = "ColPosItemCode",
            [8] = "ColPosItemName",
            [9] = "ColPosOrderDate",
            [10] = "ColPosExpectedFinishDate",
            [11] = "ColPosOrderedByEmp",
            [12] = "ColPosDepartment",
            [13] = "ColPosProcessSteps",
            [14] = "ColPosAdditions",
            [15] = "ColPosProject",
            [16] = "ColPosCommission"
        };

        if (ActiveUserModel.GetAdminPermission()) {
            IsCancelButtonVisible = true;
        }

        deleteFilter();
    }

    private ICollectionView orders;

    public ICollectionView Orders
    {
        get
        {
            return this.orders;
        }

        set
        {
            this.orders = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Orders);
        }
    }

    #region Column Properties

    public int ColPosDue
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosDue"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosDue");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosStatus
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosStatus"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosStatus");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosMat
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosMat"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosMat");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosProgress
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosProgress"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosProgress");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosCode
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosCode"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosCode");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosOrderDate
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosOrderDate"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosOrderDate");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosOrderedByEmp
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosOrderedByEmp"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosOrderedByEmp");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosDepartment
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosDepartment"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosDepartment");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosProcessSteps
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosProcessSteps"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosProcessSteps");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosExpectedFinishDate
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosExpectedFinishDate"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosExpectedFinishDate");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosQuantity
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosQuantity"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosQuantity");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosUnit
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosUnit"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosUnit");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosItemCode
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosItemCode"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosItemCode");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosItemName
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosItemName"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosItemName");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosAdditions
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosAdditions"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosAdditions");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosProject
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosProject"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosProject");
        }
    }

    public int ColPosCommission
    {
        get { return GetColPosition("ColPosCommission"); }
        set
        {
            ReorderColPositions(value, "ColPosCommission");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Rearrange Columns
    private int GetColPosition(string columnName) {
        return ColPositions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == columnName).Key;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

The Code above is one of my first tries when I was on the step to save the correct columnorder in a dictionary. But once the loading of the column values begins the values of the dictionary is switched around and wont fit to the original values anymore and so the column order of the user is messed up. Im missing an idea to solve that. Initially the values may not change until the datagrid is completely loaded then the values may change...

Another try was to set backing fields for the properties and just call a method at start to grab the wanted display indexes out of the dictionary. Since the automatic reordering happens I've tried to reflect the actual property state and compare it to the display index in the dictionary and redo the setting of each column till its ordered in the right way.

```
private void SetInitialValues() {
        this.ColPositions = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            [0] = "ColPosDue",
            [1] = "ColPosCode",
            [2] = "ColPosStatus",
            [3] = "ColPosMat",
            [4] = "ColPosProgress",
            [5] = "ColPosQuantity",
            [6] = "ColPosUnit",
            [7] = "ColPosItemCode",
            [8] = "ColPosItemName",
            [9] = "ColPosOrderDate",
            [10] = "ColPosExpectedFinishDate",
            [11] = "ColPosOrderedByEmp",
            [12] = "ColPosDepartment",
            [13] = "ColPosProcessSteps",
            [14] = "ColPosAdditions",
            [15] = "ColPosProject",
            [16] = "ColPosCommission"
        };

        if (ActiveUserModel.GetAdminPermission()) {
            IsCancelButtonVisible = true;
        }

        deleteFilter();
        SetAllColumnPositions();
    }
  
   #region private Members of Column Properties
    private int colPosDue;
    private int colPosStatus;
    ...more columns follow
    #endregion

    public int ColPosDue
    {
        get { return colPosDue; }
        set
        {
            colPosDue = value;
        }
    }

    public int ColPosStatus
    {
        get { return colPosStatus; }
        set
        {
            colPosStatus = value;
        }
    }
   ...more column properties follow

  private void SetAllColumnPositions() {
        bool isOrderRearranged;

        foreach (int column in ColPositions.Keys.ToList()) {
            SetActualColumnOrder();
            isOrderRearranged = true;
            do {
                if (ActualColPositions[column] != ColPositions[column]) {
                    switch (ColPositions[column]) {
                        case "ColPosDue":
                            colPosDue = column;
                            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ColPosDue);
                            isOrderRearranged = false;
                            break;
                       //...for each column
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                } 
            } while (isOrderRearranged);
        }
    }

    private void SetActualColumnOrder() {
        Type type = this.GetType();

        ActualColPositions = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 16; i++) {
            ActualColPositions.Add(i, "");
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties()) {
            if (prop.Name.StartsWith("ColPos")) {
                ActualColPositions[int.Parse(prop.GetValue(this).ToString())] = prop.Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'v tried to do these steps starting in a reverse order when setting the new display indexes (starting from position no 16) and so on.

After the display indexes have set in the correct way via the constructer invocation the column properties are set once again and I really dont know why and when else I should set the indexes.
[image]

[image]

Thats the final value...

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: OMG... once again I'm really sorry for posting that question. Through the detailed describing of the problem I've noticed it may be a completely wrong try to handle the arranging of the columns while the view is initialised. I simply came, when I've checked the final value of the above mentioned column to the conclusion its not possible to set the values in that scope. Once Im catching the right time in point (when datagrid is loaded) I can set the values without any problems. Just believe me this issue caused some real annoying headaches for almost a whole week.

Comment: But anyways I have to iterate over the display index untill the order fits... wondering why I can't set the indexes on one strike. Im iterating - not just setting em at once - over all indexes of the user settings and thats the same as the user would switch the columns on his own. So why the hell doesnt this work as expected????